# I'd like to disable Shotwell

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, shotwell

I need help with either disabling or removing Shotwell on Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried to load picturess from my camera and they were intercepted by Shotwell. I'd like to have them go to my designated folder like they used to in order for me to edit them before uploading to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type the magic words:

```
sudo apt purge shotwell
```

- `sudo`: SuperUser DO
- `apt`: Advanced Package Tool

the rest is pretty obvious...

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment.  Answer edited in the meantime.